# Bash Case menu - dynamic choices

Tags: bash, menu, case

I'm not sure what the policy is here on asking followup questions.  So please excuse me if i'm breaking protocol.  Earlier I was constructing a menu in bash ( [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659826/bash-menu-return-to-menu-after-selection-made-and-executed) )

And so far I've got it working really good.  Code here.

```
while [[ 1 ]]
do
    cat -n "$dumpfile"
    read -p "Please make a selection, select q to quit: " choice
    case $choice in
            # Check for digits
    [0-9] )   dtvariable=$(sed -n "$choice"p "$dumpfile")
              $dtvariable            ;;
     q|Q)
         break
           ;;
      *)
           echo "Invalid choice"
           ;;
    esac
done
```

Except - that works great for menu items up to 9.  The menu will be dynamic - could have 1 item, 20 items, or 197 items.  I've tried changing [0-9] to be [0-9][0-9] to see if it would take 12.  But it doesn't.  Can anyone put me on the right path?  I suppose I could just remove the [0-9] part and take anything that is not q.  But wouldn't it be better to look for numbers?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do some validation on `$choice`:

```
case $choice in
     # Check for digits
    +([0-9]))
        lines=($(wc -l ))
        if (( choice > 0 && choice <= lines ))
        then
            dtvariable=$(sed -n "$choice"p "$dumpfile")
            $dtvariable            ;;
        fi
# etc.
```

Comment: Thanks Dennis.  I went without the extglob part - and it tests out fantastically.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I got to work.  The primary differences are the addition of `shopt -s extglob`, which turns on extended pattern matching, and the `+([0-9])` pattern, which 
is the bash equivalent of regular expression `[0-9]+`

```
shopt -s extglob
while [[ 1 ]]
do
    read -p "Please make a selection, select q to quit: " choice
    case $choice in
            # Check for digits
    +([0-9]))  
         echo $choice ;;
     q|Q)
         break
           ;;
      *)
           echo "Invalid choice"
           ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Thanks, it's tossing an syntax error near unexpected token `(' error right by the +([0-9]))  I can't see any extra spaces or anything else.  still looking.

Comment: did you make sure to add the extglob?  It won't work without it, since the +(...) syntax is enabled by extglob.